# How to mock a timeout in python ? for pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Okay so im trying to write a pytest for a python function that has a while loop which will only exit if a certain condition is met or will continue to check for that condition for x amount of time.

Now Im trying to write a pytest for it and to break out of the loop im able to obviously mock the condition the loop is looking for but while writing pytest to test if it timeout works and shows the correct error is where im not able to think straight.
Here is a demo code

```
flag = False
while time.time() < end_time:
   if condition:
        do_something()
        flag = True
        break
return flag
```

I'v tried a couple of things but nothing solid came of it.

Comment: You can use the pytest-timeout

Comment: If you've tried a couple of things, remember to [talk about and/or show what you tried](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're looking to have:

a) your code must enter the while loop
b) your code must not exit out of the loop because of the `break` statement.

I am going to assume that in the setup code, you've gotten `end_time` by doing some operation after calling `time.time()`. I'm also going to assume you don't want to wait for the actual duration of the timeout.

You can handle this by:

1. Setting up a mock of the `time` module so that `.time()` has 3 return values:

   - The initial one to set up the `end_time`
   - The first time the loop enters, which will be a value smaller than `end_time`
   - The second iteration of the loop, which will have a value larger than `end_time`
2. Passing the right parameters (or mocking things used to calculate `condition`) so that the first time it enters the loop, the `if` statement evaluates as `False`.

I would suggest considering whether or not you actually need that test- with the demo code, your test isn't giving you any information by using this setup that you don't get by just causing the loop to never execute in the first place unless you have additional code after that `if` block

Comment: you are right I don't necessarily need the test but this was something I was trying out of curiosity, if it is possible to play with timeout loops using pytest.

Comment: @vkp entirely fair! It also might help if you have or might eventually have any code in that loop outside of the if statement. Did you get a chance to try out that method?